# Are there EXI processors that serialize the in-memory infoset to a file on the computer?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, exi

Here's my understanding of how XML Schema validation occurs with EXI: An EXI processor converts an EXI-encoded XML instance document to an in-memory infoset. The in-memory infoset is then validated against the XML Schema. Do I understand correctly?

I heard that some EXI processors serialize the in-memory infoset to a file on the computer. That would be a huge security risk for my system. Are you aware of any EXI processors that serialize the infoset to a file on the computer? Or, does the EXI specification explicitly prohibit EXI-compliant processors from doing that?

Comment: I think I can answer the last part: the EXI specification describes conformance of an EXI processor in terms of its inputs and outputs, and not its internal workings. It would be very unusual if it did anything else. You're asking about "quality of implementation" issues, not specification issues.

Comment: I agree with what have been said before. The EXI specification describes how certain XML events (elements, attributes, ..) are to be represented. It also speaks about "how" the XML Information Set is mapped to the EXI format (see https://www.w3.org/TR/exi/#InfosetMapping).

Having said that, in general EXI implementations will allow input based on various interfaces (e.g. SAX, DOM, StAX, ...)